# Wildfly 8.1.0 run standlone in alternate configuration

Tags: jboss, wildfly-8

I am migrating from JBoss 5 to Wildfly. One of our server has group of small web applications that are deployed in two instances of the same JBoss, namely customappgrp1 & customappgrp2, with two custom configurations.

```
$ /home/apps/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server
+ all
+ default
+ minimal
+ standard
+ web
+ customappgrp1
+ customappgrp2
```

The server instances are started with the below command

```
$ ./run.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -c customappgrp1 -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01 -Dcom.a2wi.global.prop=/home/apps/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/customappgrp1/prop/global.properties -Dglobal.properties.loc=/home/apps/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/customappgrp1/prop/global.properties 

$ ./run.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -c customappgrp2 -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-02 -Dcom.a2wi.global.prop=/home/apps/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/customappgrp2/prop/global.properties -Dglobal.properties.loc=/home/apps/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/customappgrp2/prop/global.properties
```

I want to run multiple instances of Wildfly standalone with custom configuration, how do I do it? Is the same option available in the Wildfly too? Can a custom configuration be separated like the earlier version of JBoss in Wildfly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this in Wildfly. Have a separate directory, say mystandalone, parallel to standalone directory. All the directories inside this will follow the default `standalone` structure. Copy the war files on both the directories inside `deployments`, or you can deploy using the console too. Use the below command to start the server

```
$ standalone.bat
```

This will start the server using default standalone directory in 8080 port

```
$ standalone.bat -Djboss.server.base.dir=/home/apps/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/mystandalone -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1010
```

`jboss.server.base.dir` points by default to the standalone directory

`jboss.socket.binding.port-offset` is to set the port, 1010 will start the server in 8080+1010

Comment: Thanks!  There's a little more detail with the same information here: http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/using-multiple-instances-of-wildfly